# Button click not running javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

I have a button a page that I want to hide/unhide a field below it:

```
<button id="post1-new-comment-button" type="button">Click</button>
<input id="post1-new-comment" name="comment[body]" size="50" type="text" />
```

with the following css

```
#post1-new-comment {
    display: none;
}
```

and javascript

```
$(function() {
    return $("#post1-new-comment-button").click(function() {
        return $("#post1-new-comment").val("").toggle();
    });
});
```

However nothing happens when the button is clicked.  What am I doing wrong here?
On jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Z5hqZ/

Comment: For starters, you're not including jQuery on your jsfiddle...

Comment: Not for starters. For the answer. Including jQuery 1.9.1 makes the script work fine.

Comment: That was really dumb of me. The real problem ended up being with the CoffeeScript I was using to generate the javaScript, which I didn't look at until it looked like it wasn't working on jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember to include `jQuery` when you want to use it, as it's not on your fiddle, also your html is wrong, on the fiddle you have:

```
<button id="post1-new-comment-button" type="button">
```

It should be:

```
<button id="post1-new-comment-button"></button>
```

Otherwise, the input will be inside the button. On your example, you're not closing the `<button>` tag, also there's no need to add `type="button"` and you don't need `return` on your JavaScript either...

Updated working example: http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/VKGdv/

Comment: True but this is not the cause of the problem. Your comment above was.

Comment: @AlienWebguy right, but with the wrong html on the example fiddle the op has, the input is inside the button, and I'm assuming that's not the intended output...

Comment: Right but my point was the problem was JS not running, which has nothing to do with DOM syntax errors.

Comment: @AlienWebguy good point, indeed that was the main issue...

Answer (score 1):

Your fiddle wasn't working because you didn't have jquery in it. I updated it and removed the return.

http://jsfiddle.net/Z5hqZ/5/

```
$(function() {
  $("#post1-new-comment-button").click(function() {
    $("#post1-new-comment").val("").toggle();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
    $("#post1-new-comment-button").click(function() {
        $("#post1-new-comment").val("").toggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For hide/unhide-

```
$(function() {
    $("#post1-new-comment-button").click(function() {
        $("#post1-new-comment").toggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. and dont forget to set library at jsfiddle to jQuery, and execute script on DOM ready

```
$(function() {
$("#post1-new-comment-button").click(function() {
    $("#post1-new-comment").toggle();
});
```

});

Here is working link: http://jsfiddle.net/Z5hqZ/2/

And don;t forget closing tag for button

Answer (score 0):

Actually all the above/below:

1. You need to include jQuery
2. Your button needs a closing tag (and preferably some text to show on the button in between)
3. Use just the following :

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#post1-new-comment-button").click(function() {
       $("#post1-new-comment").toggle();
     });
   });
   ```